# i have run time error in selenium test NG, Any Solutions Available?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, testng, pom.xml, testng.xml

```
Error1:Suite file C:\Users\Hp\Selinium Workspace pratice\xmlfile\testing.xml is not a valid file
Error2: Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M8:test[m [1m(default-test)[m on project [36mxmlfile[m:

[[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging
```

while Executing My Project I find this Error, I Done correctly in Pom.xml by calling plug-ins and properties
I am facing issue while calling multiple classes alone

Comment: good to have po.xml and testng.xml files